# Typescript generics for 2nd optional argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Generics in typescript is pretty advanced for me. But I managed to got this working

```
export type Events = {
  LOGIN: undefined
  NAVIGATION: {
    screen: string
  }
  SUPPORT: {
    communication_method: 'chat' | 'email' | 'phone'
  }
}

export function trackEvent<K extends keyof Events>(eventName: K, eventValues: Events[K]) {
  if (Platform.OS === 'web') return
  logEvent(eventName, eventValues ?? {})
}

trackEvent('LOGIN', undefined) // no TS error
// is there a way to make this work with just trackEvent('LOGIN') 

trackEvent('SUPPORT') //  TS error because missing 2nd argument
trackEvent('SUPPORT', { communication_method: 'chat' }) // TS helps writing this
```

But wondering if there is a way to make this work with just `trackEvent('LOGIN')` without error and `trackEvent('SUPPORT')` with error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use a *rest parameter*. If the type of `Events[K]` is `undefined`, the type of the rest parameter evaluates to an empty tuple. The empty tuple forbids additional arguments from being passed to the function. It can be optionally replaced by `[undefined?]` if you still want to be able to provide `undefined`.

```
export function trackEvent<K extends keyof Events>(
  eventName: K, 
  ...[eventValues]: (Events[K] extends undefined ? [] : [Events[K]])
) {
  if (Platform.OS === 'web') return
  logEvent(eventName, eventValues ?? {})
}

trackEvent('LOGIN', undefined)
//                  ~~~~~~~~~ Expected 1 arguments, but got 2

trackEvent('SUPPORT')
//          ~~~~~~~ Expected 2 arguments, but got 1

trackEvent('LOGIN') // 
trackEvent('SUPPORT', { communication_method: 'chat' }) //
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-MgjLBkAAmJrW2EI8UO45OVwpT0iX0MIPBrCh8MqrMxuMJ7pEFNp0AZ5CR3M2gv2x2DF0W+iAXg3ALI7tD7du6RYcJdkrsooCu-kCIShD1iCWSeVeiFqI7AE6AA)

Comment: thank you Tobias, that was a cleaver way to do it. I edited your answer to include the use of `arg[0]` in the implementation.

Comment: @Norfeldt - You can also destructure it directly in the parameter with `...[eventValues]`. See my edit